# Set fill-column for all cider output

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I would like to set fill-column value for all cider output. I'm using:

```
(require 'cider)
(setq cider-show-error-buffer              nil
      cider-docview-fill-column            76
      cider-stacktrace-fill-column         76
      nrepl-buffer-name-show-port          nil
      cider-repl-display-in-current-window t
      cider-repl-result-prefix             ";; => ")
```

But when I call `meta`, I get this:

```
user> (meta #'str)
;; => {:added "1.0", :ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name str, :file "clojure/core.clj", :static true, :column 1, :line 511, :tag java.lang.String, :arglists ([] [x] [x & ys]), :doc "With no args, returns the empty string. With one arg x, returns\n  x.toString().  (str nil) returns the empty string. With more than\n  one arg, returns the concatenation of the str values of the args."}
```

Everything in one line. I bet there is some variable `cider-...-fill-column` that will help me. I googled it, but found only `cider-docview-fill-column` and `cider-stacktrace-fill-column`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such REPL fill-column variable, but you can enable pretty-printing of eval results in the REPL (see the REPL's menu). You can enable it from your config like this:

```
(setq cider-repl-use-pretty-printing t)
```

Comment: Yes, `M-x cider-repl-toggle-pretty-printing` works. Can I enable it in my .emacs file, so that it will work by default?

Comment: Could you tell why pretty-printing disables `cider-repl-result-prefix` ?  Can they coexist?